# Creating a sticky header on scroll, position fixed breaks the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I am making a sticky header on scroll so when the header bar gets to the top of the page it will stick there. The issue I'm having is with the position fixed that is required to make it stick to the top of the page.

When I apply position fixed to the header when it is required to become sticky it overflows from the wrapper where I want it to keep its current form and just stick to the top, I have played around with a lot of different ways to code this and have not found a solution.

Please see what I mean when you scroll on this page : http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/297/Fujifilm_FinePix_XP80
(The div with the RED border is what I want to stick to the top)

HTML :

```
<!-- FIXED HEADER -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="compare1_fixed">
            <div class="compare1_fixed_score">
            </div>
            <div class="compare1_fixed_name">
                <?php echo $brand['brand'] . " " . $model['model'] . " " . "Specifications"; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="compare1_fixed_social">
                <div class="compare1_fixed_social_icon">
                    <a href="http://google.com">
                        <img src="http://specced.co.uk/images/ui/facebook.png">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://google.com">
                        <img src="http://specced.co.uk/images/ui/twitter.png">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://google.com">
                        <img src="http://specced.co.uk/images/ui/google.png">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://google.com">
                        <img src="http://specced.co.uk/images/ui/email.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.compare1_fixed {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    clear: both;
    border:1px solid red;
}

. compare1_fixed_fixed {
    position:fixed;
}

.compare1_fixed_score {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    background-color:#222222;
}

.compare1_fixed_social {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
}

.compare1_fixed_social_icon {
    display: inline-block;
}

.compare1_fixed_social_icon img {
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.compare1_fixed_social_icon img:hover {
    opacity:.7;
}


.compare1_fixed_name {
    width:calc(100% - 400px);
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
/* STICKY HEADER */
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {

      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.compare1_fixed').addClass('compare1_fixed_fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 201) {
      $('.compare1_fixed_fixed').removeClass('compare1_fixed_fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You might want to add a z-index in there to keep it above everything.

Comment: Please can you see the website though the red border overflows

Answer (score 0):

Position Fixed will make the element occupy full page width,

Modify Your CSS accordingly

```
  .compare1_fixed_fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        width: 87%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

hope this helps..